# How far can we take this probabilistic argument?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, probabilistic-method

$\newcommand{\set}[1]{\{#1\}}$ $\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}$

## The Problem

Let $G=(V, E)$ be a (finite, simple) graph.
Let $\chi:V\to \set{R, B}$ be a $2$-coloring of $V$.
We say that a vertex $v\in V$ is $\chi$-**good** if the number of neighbors of $v$ which get the same color as $v$ is no more than the number of neighbors of $v$ which get different color than $v$.
In other words,
$$
|\set{u\in N(v):\ \chi(u) = \chi(v)}| \leq |\set{u\in N(v):\ \chi(u)\neq \chi(v)}|
$$
where $N(v)$ is the set of all the neighbors of $v$.
A $2$-coloring $\chi$ is said to be **admissible** if each vertex $v\in V$ is $\chi$-good.

Consider the following problem.

> **Problem.** Show that every graph admits an admissible $2$-coloring.

A proof of this problem can be given as follows. Given a $2$-coloring $\chi$ of $G$, we call an edge **nice** if the endpoints of this edge have different colors.
Choose a $2$-coloring $\chi_0$ of $V$ which has the maximum number of nice edges.
We claim that any such coloring is admissible.
To see this, assume on the contrary that $\chi_0:V\to \set{R, B}$ is not admissible.
So there is a vertiex $v$ whihc is not $\chi_0$-good.
But now flipping the color of $v$ increases the number of nice edges, producing a coloring which has more nice edges than present in $\chi_0$.
This contradicts the maximality assumption.

## The Probabilistic Argument

However, I would like to see how much can we get out of a probabilistic argument.
The following argument shows that there exists a $2$-coloring which has at least $|V|/2$ good vertices.

Color each vertex independently red or blue with probability $1/2$.
So we can now talk about a random coloring.
For each $v\in V$, let $G_v$ be a random variable valued in $\set{0, 1}$ which takes the value $1$ if $v$ is good, otherwise it takes the value $0$.
Clearly, $P[G_v=1]=1/2$, because a vertex will be good of not good with equal probability.
Therefore, $\E[G_v]=1/2$, and hence, by linearity of expectation, we have $\E[\sum_{v\in V} G_v]=|V|/2$.
This means that there must exist a coloring where we have at least $|V|/2$ good vertices.

> **Question.**
> How much further can we take this? Can we show, for instance, that there must exist a coloring with at least $3|V|/4$ good vertices via a probabilistic approach too?